# Equivalent of goto of c++ in Java in a specific scenario

Tags: java, c++

I am replacing a old C++ code with Java:I know there is no equivalent of goto in java as it causes many surprising errors and unintended loop terminations.

C++ code: //I have skipped the actual code

```
for(//some condition){

  if (excl(grds[i],0)) 
   {
       //do something 
       goto breakout;
   }
   //some more code
breakout:
   //rest of the code
}//end of for loop
```

Java representation:

```
for(//some condition){

  if (excl(grds[i],0)) 
   {
      //do something 
   }
  else
   {
   //some more code
   }

   //rest of the code
}//end of for loop
```

I have kept the "some more code" part in the else section so I guess it will function same as the breakout. When the if condition is true it wont go to the else part and rest of the code will be executed as usual. I guess break or continue wont serve the purpose as we need to any way run the rest of the code section for all iterations.

Is this the correct way of representing this C++ code in Java?

Comment: Your `//do something` in your java code is not in your c++ code?

Comment: included do somthing in c++ also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that would be the better way — in Java, and in C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(//some condition){

  if (!(excl(grds[i],0))) 
   {
      //some more code
   }

   //rest of the code
}//end of for loop
```

**Edit**: after your clarification, the way you did it is fine.

Why can't you have it like this?

In your C++ code, `//some more code` is only executed when the condition is false and the `//rest` is always executed. So put that in the if.

Comment: My initial thought was that it should be done that way, so you don't have an if that does nothing, then an else that actually executes code. However, the Java code has a comment saying `do something` in the if part, so I guess the C++ code is actually doing something before the `goto` statement.

Comment: @Anthony added a comment to the question, maybe the author can elaborate on this.

Comment: Though, of course, `not` isn't valid Java syntax, so it should be `if(!(excl(grds[i],0)))`.

Comment: @Anthony Edited, thanks! Too much python, happens all the time ;)

Comment: yes some more code should only execute when the condition is false , thats y i have put it in the else part.

Comment: @David Hamman the do_something block was not in the original c++ code, thats why I asked as a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way:

```
for(//some condition){

   if(!excl(grds[i],0)) 
   {
      //some more code
   }

   //rest of the code
}//end of for loop
```

You really shouldn't be using `goto` in C++. As a side note, in Java you can have named blocks that can be used to simulate a `goto`:

```
namedBlock:
{
    // some code

    if(condition)
        break namedBlock;

    // some more code
}
// rest of the code
```

But this is awful practice. Don't do it. Forget I even mentioned it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

To be more precise, that's the <del>correct</del> best way of representing that code in C++ as well. Why use `goto` instead of a simple `if`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack

```
for(//some condition){
    do { // note this *do* 
        if (excl(grds[i],0)) 
        {
            break; // out of do/while
        }
        //some more code
    }
    while(false); // do only once

      //rest of the code
}//end of for loop
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your opening comment explains why you got a downvote, doncha think?

Comment: @David, not really no. I supplied a working solution, there are some situations in which `do { } while(0);` can be useful but this case is probably not one of them. I think that tagging it as a hack shows that it should be avoided but can be used if other considerations take precedence (e.g. minimal change relative to C++ version for diff)

Comment: What a coincidence, today's [Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Legacy-Handover.aspx) isn't one of those cases either!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure people will hate me for this, but you can get closer to the `goto` statement in Java than the if/else example.  For instance, you can do:

```
for(/*some condition*/){
    breakout: {
        if (excl(grds[i],0)) {
           break breakout;  //this will jump to the end of the "breakout" block
        }

        //some more code
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

Of course, this is not an example of good Java coding style, and just because this can be done doesn't mean it should be done.  Really you should stick with the if/else.

Answer (score 0):

There are occasions, very rare occasions, when using `goto` is exactly the right choice in C++. The example shown is not one of them. This is a `goto` that should never have been used, period. A `goto` has zero reason for existence if you can eliminate the `goto` with no additional variables, no increase in the complexity.

Some valid uses of `goto` in C++ can be easily eliminated in Java.

- C and C++ do not have a way to break or continue out of a nested loop. Java does. When the target of a `goto` is immediately before some close brace, change the `goto label` with `continue label`. When the target of a `goto` is immediately *after* some close brace, change the `goto label` with `break label`. (The label statement may need to be moved around.)
- Some C++ code uses `goto` in lieu of `throw` for local error handling / local error recovery. C++ exceptions have a pretty stiff performance penalty. If the code is being converting to Java it's kinda obvious that performance is not an issue. Use Java exceptions for this kind of `goto`.